# ModelMapper return Null in DTO fields while mapping from Entity to DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, modelmapper

ModelMapper returns `null` in my DTO fields while mapping from Entity Object to Dto. Anyone please explain why I am getting **Null** response.

**`TestEntity`**

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="TestEntity")
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="test_name")
    private String test_name;
}
```

**`TestEntityDto`**

```
@Data
public class TestEntityDto {

    private long id;
    private String test_name;
}
```

**`TestService`**

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    @Autowired
    TestEntityRepo testEntityRepo;

    public TestEntityDto getAllTestList() {
        List<TestEntity> testEntity= testEntityRepo.findAll();
        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        TestEntityDto testEntityDto = mapper.map(TestEntity.class, TestEntityDto.class);

        return  testEntityDto;
    }
}
```

**Actual Result:**

```
{
   "id": 0,
   "test_name": null
}
```

**Expected Result:**

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "test_name": "Test"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to map `List<TestEntity>` to `TestEntityDto` which is wrong.
Try to map for each `TestEntity` using ModelMapper and make list of `TestEntityDto`.

```
public List<TestEntityDto> getAllTestList() {

    List<TestEntity> testEntity= testEntityRepo.findAll();
    List<TestEntityDto> testEntityDtos = new ArrayList<TestEntityDto>();
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
    for(TestEntity perTestEntity :testEntity){
        TestEntityDto testEntityDto = mapper.map(perTestEntity , TestEntityDto.class);
         testEntityDtos.add(testEntityDto);
    }
    return  testEntityDtos;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `private String test_name;` in class but in dto there is no field named `test_name`.

Use `private String testName;` in `TestEntity` class.

Or

Use `private String test_name;` in `TestEntityDto` class.

**Update** use `STRICT` mapping and use testEntity for source.

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
TestEntityDto testEntityDto = mapper.map(testEntity, TestEntityDto.class);
```

Comment: I update my question I renamed the field in my dto, still the same issue

Comment: issue persist. even I tried with these properties

ModelMapper modelMapper=new ModelMapper();
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setDestinationNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE);
        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSourceNameTokenizer(NameTokenizers.UNDERSCORE);

        modelMapper.getConfiguration().setFieldAccessLevel(Configuration.AccessLevel.PRIVATE);

TestEntityDto testEntityDto = modelMapper.map(testEntity, TestEntityDto.class);